# Many-to-many hierarchical relationships

Tags: sql, many-to-many

In my application I have three main tables:

1. User
2. Group
3. Role

Any combination has a many-to-many relationship.E.g. a user can be in different group, having different roles in each of them.

The easiest part is to map user and group, done by the intermediate table `User_Group`. Then, when it came to design how to link the three together I had some doubts.

[image]

**Q: Do I add another column in `User_Group`? Or create additional intermediate table?**

Thinking about the second option, I tried this:

[image]

which (I think) would make easier and tidier retrieving the information I need in the front-end:

1. Groups available for the user (`User_Group`)
2. Roles available for a group (`Group_Role`)
3. Roles available for a user in a given group (`user_Group_Role`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see anything wrong with the schema you have proposed at the end of your post.

- It ensures a `user` can be associated to a `group` without them being required to have a `role` within that `group`.
- It can ensure that a `user` can only take a `role` applicable to the specific `group`.
- It can allow the same `role` to be shared across multiple `groups`.
- It can allow a `group` without any `roles`

To shrink the schema you *can* come up with some *nice tricks*:

- Create a role for `doesn't have a role in this group`; to remove the need of `user_group`
- Create a `dummy user` for each group, that has every role the group is eligible for; to remove the need of `group_role`
- etc,etc

The down side here is that you end up needing bespoke code to deal with changes, or enforcing constraints.  The schema you propose at the end of your post can enforce all the required constraints with foreign key constraints and composite primary key constraints.  And will in general be more flexible to future changes.

I see no reason not to use the schema you have proposed, it seems perfectly correct, maintainable, understandable, and resilient to me.

Comment: Well I'm glad to hear that. Since it's my very first project of this kind. Thanks very much

Answer (score 1):

I would go with additional column in existing joining table. You can still fairly easily answer all your questions:

1. Groups available for the user

   ```
   select *
   from Roles r
   join JoiningTableName j on r.Role_Id = j.Role_Id
   where j.User_Id = myUserId
   ```
2. Roles available for a group

   ```
   select *
   from Roles r
   join JoiningTableName j on r.Role_Id = j.Role_Id
   where j.Group_Id = myGroupId
   ```
3. Roles available for a user in a given group

   ```
   select *
   from Roles r
   join JoiningTableName j on r.Role_Id = j.Role_Id
   where j.User_Id = myUserId and j.Group_Id = myGroupId
   ```

Comment: The one subtle detail with an additional column is, for users added to a group, with *no* roles. That would either introduce a NULL requirement or "Member" role.

Comment: @user2864740 - I don't see a problem with a `NoRole` or `Member` role, could you elaborate on why you perceive it to be an issue, or are you just pointing out the requirement?

Comment: @MatBailie Not that there *is* a problem, but it's a "possible complication" - I've changed it to "subtle detail" to make the comment less .. stigmatized?